# How can we make a certain thing inbuilt in c language with our own header file?

Tags: design, c, languages

I want to make the basic trigonometric functions in maths inbuilt functions using my own header file . so as the users can do trigonometry in c language compilers.

Comment: please be more specific. give an example of what you intend to have as a result, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: i want derivatives of some basic trigonometric functions inbuilt by creating my own header file in c language. example: dx(sinx)=cosx,

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: These functions are not built in to the C programming language. They are supplied by standard libraries. There is no requirement for a C compiler to support `sin()`, `cos()` or `tan()`, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make new functions "built-in" to C without changing the compiler. However, you *can* write and extend libraries with new functions that your programs can then reuse wherever they want. For that, you need to compile a library with the functions, your program needs to include the library header file, and the linker has to include the object code for your functions. Please elaborate if you need more specific help.

Comment: can we  make our new header file in c language ?if yes then how?eg i want to make a a new header file name "derivative"and include function like chain rule etc

Comment: QUE  wht is the coding for pow function?